# ¿Se puede hacer un buscador en tiempo real usando de filtro listas desplegables?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

tengo un buscador en tiempo real el cual al seleccionar una opción de un `select` la idea es que filtre los datos y muestra los que coincidan con la selección. El tema es que no filtra y no sé qué hacer. Tenía un buscador normal con el típico `input`, lo que hice fue cambiarlo por un `select` y dejó de funcionar. No sé cómo hacer que funcione.
Les dejo mi código, desde ya muchas gracias.

Buscador (consultas.php)

```
<div id="barra-de-busqueda">
  <h1>¿Qué deseas encontrar?</h1>
  <select name="busqueda" id="busqueda">
    <option value="0">Filtrar</option>
     <option value="China">China</option>
     <option value="USA">USA</option>
     <option value="UKA">UKA</option>
  </select>
</div>

<section id="tabla_resultado">

</section>
```

ajax.js

```
$(obtener_registros());

function obtener_registros(alumnos)
{
    $.ajax({
        url : 'buscando.php',
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : 'html',
        data : { alumnos: alumnos },
        })

    .done(function(resultado){
        $("#tabla_resultado").html(resultado);
    })
}

$(document).on('keyup', '#busqueda', function()
{
    var valorBusqueda=$(this).val();
    if (valorBusqueda!="")
    {
        obtener_registros(valorBusqueda);
    }
    else
        {
            obtener_registros();
        }
});
```

buscando.php

```
<?php

$conexion = new mysqli("localhost","root","","minos");


//////////////// VALORES INICIALES ///////////////////////

$tabla="";
$query="SELECT * FROM productos ORDER BY id";

///////// LO QUE OCURRE AL TECLEAR SOBRE EL INPUT DE BUSQUEDA ////////////
if(isset($_POST['alumnos']))
{
    $q=$conexion->real_escape_string($_POST['alumnos']);
    $query=" SELECT
            p.id,
            p.descri,
            p.precio,
            m.nombre_m,
            c.nombre_c,
            p.pais,
            p.imagen
        FROM productos p
        INNER JOIN marcas m     ON p.marca  = m.id
        INNER JOIN categorias c ON p.catego = c.id
        WHERE   m.nombre_m LIKE '%".$q."%'
                OR c.nombre_c LIKE '%".$q."%'
                OR p.pais LIKE '%".$q."%'
        ";
}



if(!isset($_POST['alumnos']))
{
    $query=" SELECT
            p.id,
            p.descri,
            p.precio,
            m.nombre_m,
            c.nombre_c,
            p.pais,
            p.imagen
        FROM productos p
        INNER JOIN marcas m     ON p.marca  = m.id
        INNER JOIN categorias c ON p.catego = c.id
        ";
}



$buscarAlumnos=$conexion->query($query);
if ($buscarAlumnos->num_rows > 0)
{
    $tabla.=
    '<table class="table">
        <tr class="bg-primary">
                               <td>id</td>
                           <td>descri</td>
                           <td>precio</td>
                           <td>marca</td>
                           <td>catego</td>
                           <td>pais</td>
                           <td>imagen</td>
        </tr>';




    while($filaAlumnos= $buscarAlumnos->fetch_assoc())
    {

        $tabla.= '<tr>
            <td>'.$filaAlumnos['id'].'</td>
            <td>'.utf8_encode($filaAlumnos['descri']).'</td>
            <td>'.$filaAlumnos['precio'].'</td>
            <td>'.utf8_encode($filaAlumnos['nombre_m']).'</td>
            <td>'.utf8_encode($filaAlumnos['nombre_c']).'</td>
            <td>'.$filaAlumnos['pais'].'</td>
            <td><img src='.$filaAlumnos['imagen'].' width="50" height="50"></td>
         </tr>
        ';

    }

    $tabla.='</table>';
} else
    {
        $tabla="No se encontraron coincidencias con sus criterios de búsqueda.";
    }


echo $tabla;
?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Intenta cambiar en el `Ajax.js` `keyup` por un `change`.

Comment: Funcionó, me ahorraste muuucho tiempo jajaja, gracias

Comment: Jajajaja de nada, suerte compañero.

Comment: Si bien la respuesta resulto útil, es muy corta en contenido y no explica el por que del cambio, considera editar y mejorar tu aporte de modo que el OP comprenda la razón